# TextBlock in a ListBox does not wrap

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I have this ListBox with 2 TextBlock's in it:

```
<ListBox Name="TransactionList" Margin="25,0,12,12" Height="362" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" Height="146" />
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I run the app, the TextBlocks do not wrap; How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At what point are you expecting it to wrap? You have to tell it at what point by setting a `Width` on the `TextBlock`. You could also restrain the `Width` of the `TextBlock` setting a parent's `Width` property, although in your case, setting it on the `StackPanel` won't have this effect because it doesn't size its content.

Answer (score 3):

Put the ListBox inside a ScrollViewer and set the attached property ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility on the listbox to disabled. Then the text will be wrapped at any size the window is sized to.

```
<ScrollViewer>
     <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <!-- Your ItemTemplate -->
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

The textblocks does not have any width set. Please set with to the textblocks (say 10) and it should work fine.

Comment: thank you,very easy but i thought that was correct set auto width!